# Winnovative HTML to PDF takes a long time

Tags: winnovative

We have succcessfully used Winnovate HTML to PDF converter in our solution in our lower environments (development and testing). But when we deploy this to production, the external facing server, which is in the DMZ, is causing some slowness which we cannot resolve.

We have a page that has a link that, when clicked, converts the page to PDF and then downloads it for the user. In development and staging, the PDF generates within a couple of seconds but in production it is taking anywhere from a minute to two minutes.

We have gone through troubleshooting steps in the Winnovative FAQs but we cannot pinpoint why this behavior occurs in one environment and not the other.

When we logged into the server and tried the PDF it was slow there itself.

Has anyone come across this issue before? Any tips on how to solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably this happens because the resources like images and css files used in the HTML code you convert are not accessible on the server executing the conversion. There might be many reasons for this: firewalls, proxies or security settings blocking access to resources hosted on the server itself, invalid base URLs, etc. You can find more details in online doucumentation http://www.winnovative-software.com/Help/html_to_pdf/Index.aspx in troubleshooting page.

Comment: @Gabbar, were you able to resolve your issue? we're having the same issue... I wish the winnovative html to pdf converter was able to communicate what the exact issue is when this is encountered.

Comment: Okay, so we had the baseURL pointing to a CDN, and for whatever reason, it stopped working to pull in an image and some css files (definitely used to work). The HTML version works fine pulling from the CDN for those resources. THE PDF version through Winnovative's conversion library apparently could not. We change the baseURL to point to the same server where the website app resides and it all works now.

Comment: If this helps anyone, the issue was the fonts website URL in the CSS file. The answer above is correct and the best way to resolve issues like these is to comment out each reference one by one and test the PDF generation.